# AngularJS - $broadcast an event across a URL change

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast

On the main page of my app I have a function that on click it will send the user to a different URL and also $broadcast an event to the controller of that view page.

If Im on a random page and click on that function, I go to the desired URL however the event is not "received". However, if I'm already on the desired page and I $broadcast the event, the controller will receive the event.

How can I make it receive the event when it comes from a different URL?

Here we have the function that is on the main page and across all app:

```
$scope.goToProfile = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('rootEvent', 'Hi there!!');
    $location.url("/profile");
}
```

And here we have the function of the controller of the generated ng-view:

```
    $scope.$on('rootEvent', function (event, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Why do this at all? You might be dealing with an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The other controller instance won't exist at the time you do the broadcast.

Comment: @rmlan I'm doing this because when the user triggers that function, I want to use the ID of the element he's clicking to be used as a query to access a DB and get the whole object. Am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, that's what I thought. What's a good way arround it?

Comment: Use a url param or store relevant data in a service

Comment: @charlietfl I followed your suggestion. I didn't want to send anything visible to the user, but I guess it had to be.Thank you for your help :)